# Why doesn't my conditional formatting in excel work?

Tags: excel

I have 6 cells.

[image]

I want to make all cells whose text isn't "a", "b" or "c" have a red background colour. I tried using a formula to make a new formatting rule. My formula is: =NOT(OR("a","b","c")). However, after I click OK, nothing happens.

Comment: You need to use this `=NOT(OR(C3="a",C3="b",C3="c"))` Where `C3:C7` -> "a","b","c","d","e"

Comment: or put the list in another range and you can use: `=ISNA(MATCH(C3,$Z$1:$Z$3,0))` where `$Z$1:$Z$3` contain the `a`,`b`,`c`

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, yes this is also a best option!

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarity, refer the image below,

Formula needs to be used in Conditional Formatting

```
=NOT(OR(C3="a",C3="b",C3="c"))
```

Follow the steps:->

• Select the list range,

• From Home Tab, --> Under Styles Group --> Click Conditional Formatting,

• Click New,

• New Formatting Rule Dialog opens,

• From New Formatting Rule Dialog Box --> Select --> Use a formula to determine which cells to format

• Enter the above formula, in the edit the rule description,

• Click the Format Button --> From Fill Tab --> Choose desired color,

• Press Ok --> Ok

[image: CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING]